# Not waiting when open a txt file with notepad C++

Tags: c++, windows

When I open a .txt file with Notepad in C++, my program does not continue until I close Notepad.

How can I have my code continue instead of waiting like this?

Code:

```
    string a;
    string topicName;
    a = "C:\\Hello\\Hi\\Hi.txt";
    topicName = "notepad \"" + a + "\"";
    system(topicName.c_str());
```

Comment: Not in standard C++. But since you are working with Windows take a look at the CreateProcess function. That will do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [popen](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/popen.html) instead of `system`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    popen("notepad.exe", "r");
    std::cout << "I'm still running!" << std::endl;
}
```

I compiled this with `g++` on Windows 10 64-bit and it works.

Comment: This answer would be better if you explained it, perhaps linking to relevant documentation too.

Comment: Linked documentation.  I would explain it if I understood it.  All I know is `popen` can execute a program asynchronously and returns a pointer to a stream of whatever that program logs to console.  Or something like that.

Comment: Better! :) However I don't believe popen exists on Windows, I don't have a Windows machine handy right now but if you do it's worth checking that / linking a source for the claim if Microsoft have written about it somewhere.

Comment: I am on Windows 10 64-bit and it works when compiled with `g++`.

Comment: `g++` on Windows?! The world has changed it seems! It's worth clarifying this in the answer, perhaps also worth checking whether it works with Visual Studio / MSVC.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use the `system` function, you can open notepad with the `start` shell function:

```
system("start notepad c:\\my\\path\\hello.txt");
```

The `start` shell function runs things in the background. It acts as if something was "clicked" on the screen. So if you want to open `hello.txt` in the default editor rather than notepad. You can also do:

```
system("start c:\\my\\path\\hello.txt");
```

Naturally this is windows-specific, and using `system` is by many not recommended for production code.

Comment: THANKS How to set question as "finished" ?

Comment: You can't, it will always be open to allow new answers, and you are free to change your best answer at any time, which I recommend in this case since I like this answer better than my own.